# Can't move cursor after booting, unplugging helps

Tags: hardware-detection

Sometimes (but not every time) after booting into Windows, my mouse won't work.

The red light underneath won't be on, I can't move it, click doesn't work.

When I unplug it from the USB port, and plug it back in, it always works flawlessly. Same USB port or another, makes no difference.

The rest of the time, it also works flawlessly.

Just sometimes it boots and gets no power...

I tried other ports, but it keeps doing that.

Mouse is a Trust GXT.
PC is HP Omen.

Any leads?

Comment: Are you on Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The latest published driver for your mouse dates from Windows 7.

On the chance that Windows 10 has kept it, run Device Manager, find the mouse
(probably under Human Interface Devices), right-click it and select Uninstall device.
If given the option to delete the driver, select it.
Finally reboot to let Windows assign its own driver.

If this doesn't help, then there is no solution, except perhaps replacing
the mouse.